# How can I get these two divs to align in a row horizontally and keep the form-group intact?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I get these two divs to align in a row horizontally and keep the `form-group` intact?

No matter what kind of col-ms-sizing I do the two input groups will not align on the same line and I believe this is only happening because of the `form-group` class.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="PriceController as formCtrl">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="processForm()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPrice" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Price</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5 input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>

          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPrice" name="inputPrice"> <span class="input-group-addon">.95</span>

        </div>
        <label for="inputDate" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5 input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDate" name="inputDate" placeholder="Date">
          <div class="input-group input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Date <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#" id="dateToday">Today</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#" id="dateTomorrow">Tomorrow</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What size is your screen? (or the window you are running this code in)

Comment: 1366x768, is it on the same row for you?

Comment: Doesn't matter what size the screen is. I'd like it to be on the same line and  if done right it should be on the same line even in the code snippet above.

Comment: It looks like it to me, you didn't close your `<form>` tag, I don't know if that contributes to the problem. Also, you should use `col-xs` instead of `col-sm` if you want it on the same line on all screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you wrap your inputs with a `<div class="row">` and then make separate `divs` for the `col-sm-*` classes. I replaced `col-sm-*` with `col-xs-*` to ensure the snippet would not wrap.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="PriceController as formCtrl">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="processForm()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1">
            <label for="inputPrice" class="control-label">Price</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-5">
            <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>

              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPrice" name="inputPrice"> <span class="input-group-addon">.95</span>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">
            <label for="inputDate" class="control-label">Date</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-5">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDate" name="inputDate" placeholder="Date">
              <div class="input-group input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Date <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#" id="dateToday">Today</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="dateTomorrow">Tomorrow</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to wrap your inputs inside of col elements basically just nested columns. Make sure you are also using the correct sized columns for the correct screen sizes.

http://jsfiddle.net/kwd9cqn9/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <label for="inputPrice" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Price</label>
            <div class="col-lg-12 input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPrice" name="inputPrice" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">.95</span>
            </div>
        </div>

       <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
           <label for="inputDate" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Date</label>
           <div class="col-lg-12 input-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDate" name="inputDate" placeholder="Date" />
               <div class="input-group input-group-btn">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Date <span class="caret"></span>
                   </button>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                       <li><a href="#" id="dateToday">Today</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#" id="dateTomorrow">Tomorrow</a></li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The labels sit on top of the inputs.

Comment: @ghost to make the labels sit on top of the inputs remove the col-sm-1 class from them http://jsfiddle.net/kwd9cqn9/2/